# Create a file and write to it

Tags: bash

Trying to create a file auto.home under /etc and write this to the file:

```
192.168.56.101:/NFS/home/&
```

I am not doing it with commandline, but bash script.

Tried this but didnt work: `cat 192.168.56.101:/NFS/Home/& > /etc/auto.home`

Comment: Next time, please include the exact error messages you got (Permission denied in this case), it makes it easier to spot the problem and "it did not work" is not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "EOL" to indicate when you want to end writing to your file using cat as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > temp_file << EOL
192.168.56.101:/NFS/home/&
EOL
sudo mv temp_file /etc/<filename>
```

This would keep writing to `temp_file`, until it gets "EOL" meaning End of Line.

---

Refered from: [A similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875614/1317271)

Comment: This makes no difference, using a here-doc does not change the fact that your redirection needs root privileges and you will still get a permission denied error, try it.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks  a lot, had forgot about the redirection and sudo usage, edited my question adapting from your answer.

Comment: And I changed my downvote to an upvote :). Yup, this should work perfectly well. By the way, the `EOL` is any string of characters, it does not _need_ to be EOL, that's just convention. You could just as easily run `cat > foo << ARGH blah blahb ARGH`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sudo` for redirection, the command will be run with root privileges but the `>` (redirection) will not so you'll get a "Permission denied" error. Using [here-docs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) as Jobin's answer does will not help.

Instead, you can use one of these approaches:

```
echo "192.168.56.101:/NFS/home/&" | sudo tee -a /etc/auto.home
```

`tee` lets you append (`-a`) to a file, since you're running it with `sudo` it will work.

Alternatively, use a temp file and move it:

```
echo "192.168.56.101:/NFS/home/&" > home.auto && sudo mv home.auto /etc
```